# iOS 7 CA Layer Rotation in For Loop

Tags: ios, ios7, calayer

It's pure visual so I used a `CALayer`. I want to rotate each piece separate but the `CALayer` rotates around the `Center`. Currently doing this:

```
int r = 110;
int pieces = 19;

for (int i = 0; i < 19; i++)
{
    float x  = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width/2 +  r * cos( (180/pieces * i) * M_PI/180);
    float y = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width/2 + r * sin( (180/pieces * i) * M_PI/180);

    CALayer *sublayer  = [CALayer layer];
    sublayer.contents = (id) [UIImage imageNamed:@"hudDB"].CGImage;
    sublayer.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, 20, 15);

    sublayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation((180/pieces) * M_PI/180), 0, 0, 1);

    [self.layer addSublayer:sublayer];
}
```

Comment: What result does this produce, and how is it different from what you're trying to do?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Could you add a picture? Do you want to rotate each piece around it's centre or all the pieces around a shared centre? Would you like to add an animation as well?

Comment: @ZevEisenberg the layer rotates as if it is a single layer. I need to rotate each piece separate around its center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code you will need.
Alter to your needs :)

```
- (void)createHalfCircle {

    self.container = [CALayer layer];


    CGFloat radius = 100;

    for (int i = 0; i <= 180;  i+=30) {

        CGFloat xPos = radius *  cos(i * ( M_PI / 180 ));
        CGFloat yPos = radius *  sin(i * ( M_PI / 180 ));

        CAShapeLayer *rectLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
        rectLayer.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(-10, -10, 20, 20)].CGPath;
        rectLayer.fillColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
        rectLayer.position = CGPointMake(xPos, yPos);

        [self.container addSublayer:rectLayer];

    }

    self.container.position = CGPointMake( self.frame.size.width / 2, self.frame.size.height / 2);
    [self.layer addSublayer:self.container];
```

}

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    for (CAShapeLayer *rectShape in self.container.sublayers) {

        rectShape.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation( M_PI, 0, 0, 1);

    }

}
```